# $\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2}=0 $ iff the Riemann Hypothesis is true.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

**Question**  Prove that Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the statement that $$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2}=0 $$ where $\rho$ are the non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function.

**Attempt**
Assume that RH is true.

Then, $\Re(\rho)=\frac{1}{2}$

Hence, $$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2}=0 $$
**Conversely** Assume, $$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2}=0 $$
Assume on the contrary that there exists some $\rho_0$ such that $\Re(\rho_0)\neq \frac{1}{2}$. Since $0<\Re(\rho)<1$, thus let, $0<\Re(\rho_0)<\frac{1}{2}$.
How to prove the converse part?.

**Edit**
$$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2}=0 $$
Since $\rho$ has $\Im(\rho)>0$ , so $1-\bar{\rho}$ has $\Im(1-\bar{\rho})>0$.
$$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2} +    \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(1-\bar{\rho})}{|\frac{1}{2}-(1-\bar{\rho}|^2}
  =0 $$
$$\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2} +    \sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{2\Re(\rho)-1}{|\frac{1}{2}-{\rho}|^2}
  =0 $$
What to do next?

Comment: Do it as in the previous questions: group the roots in pairs and look what comes out.

Comment: @user I tried but nothing comes out as such.

Comment: Could you include your try in the question?

Comment: @user Sorry.I could not get you. How to get $\Re(\rho)=1/2$

Comment: Could you write in the question what you have tried?

Comment: @user I have written in the question my try. Please answer.

Comment: @user Sorry i could not follow.

Comment: @user I have seen some beautiful answers given by you. Please write an answer of this question. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have no time now but I come back a bit later. However one good advice I can give you right now. Never forget to accept most useful answers to your questions and upvote the answers which are somewhat less useful.

Comment: @user Please tell me if this equivalence is true?

Comment: @user After your kind advice I have upvoted the useful answers and given them a check mark.

Comment: Please do not change the question, especially if you have received an answer. Ask instead a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim in the OP is not true as $\sum_{\Im(\rho)>0}\frac{1-2\ \Re(\rho)}{|\frac{1}{2}-\rho|^2}=0$ unconditionally (the identity holds if RH true and if RH false)

By symmetry whenever $\rho$ is a root with $\Im \rho >0$, so is $1-\bar \rho$; but $\frac{1}{|1/2-\rho|^2}=\frac{1}{|\bar \rho -1/2|^2}$, while $\Re \rho + \Re (1-\bar \rho)=1$, so in the case of RH false we group the terms with $\Im \rho >0$ as above $\rho, 1-\bar \rho$ when they are distinct (in other the roots off the critical line with positive imaginary part) together and we get $0$, while the critical line zeroes give $0$ trivially as noted in the original post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Any other equivalent of the RH which you think can show a path towards it?

Comment: I have edited the question. I am extremely sorry that i had to change it. Please look at it. Now it seems true.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be cautious next time